# What to do for correct book navigation for 2 languages (always both book pages are shown)

Tags: nodes, navigation

We are using in productive system D6 (here it works!) and now we upgrade to 7.25 (it doesn't work). I have a problem to get the book navigation working in the right way. It shows always both languages in the block. How to set up it correctly?

I don't know if it is important, but here some facts from our D6 productive system:
- default language: GERMAN
- Source language for translation: GERMAN
- Second language: ENGLISH

We use [pathauto](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto) and the links to an English and German page are in that way:
DE: /content/
EN: /en/content/

Language negotiation settings: Path prefix only
Content selection mode: Only current language.

Does anyone know which is the D7 equivalent parameter or configuration for D6 "Content selection mode:Only current language"?

Thank you
Mathias